# Django - How to add items to Bootstrap dropdown?

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4

For some background I'm using Django and Bootstrap to build a to-do list as a side project. The issue I'm having is that I can't add items to the dropdown list. I want to have a dropdown to have a list of people's names but when i try to add them to the dropdown they do not appear.

this is my view. As you can see I'm passing a list of names as an example.

```
def index(request):

form = TodoForm()
people = ['person1', 'person2', 'person3']

if request.user.is_authenticated is False:
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'todo_list': [], 'form': form})

user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
todo_list = user.todo_set.all().order_by('id')
return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'todo_list': todo_list, 'form': form, 'people': people})
```

This is dropdown which I got from Bootstrap:

```
            <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Remind others
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                {% for person in people %}
                    <a class="dropdwon-item" href="#">{{ person }}</a>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
```

When I run this code, I do see the dropdown button but when I clicked, it drops down but it doesn't show any names. It's just a blank dropdown.

I know the dropdown list work because when I run the code below it works perfectly.

```
            <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Remind others
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"></a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I just noticed a mistake in the second piece of code, in line 7 the class should be "dropdown-item". I fixed it but I still have the same issue.

Comment: Could it be that its not authenticated? `if request.user.is_authenticated is False:`

Comment: @Axois Yup, that was it. Such a silly mistake. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine. However
`if request.user.is_authenticated is False:`  prevents the `people` from passing into your html page. Just remember to authenticate to view the full drop down menu :)